# Running a C# program on a website

Tags: c#, html

I have a C# application that i want to run, it is a subscribe app that can open up and take information and write it down to a excel or txt file, i want to make its link to the html as simple as possible, how do i do that, i tried a `<a href = >` link but it downloads it, i want it to open and run with out being downloaded. We have tried creating a `hta` something, but it does not work, we tried a button and that does not work either. I want it to run off the link, is there a way to do such a thing or is it because that it is `server side` that it is impossible to do so?

Edit

The client would not be putting in numbers, just `basic information, name, DOB, and email`, that is all.

Comment: It doesn't sound like this is a programming question - you might try your question on SuperUser (http://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: Don't think it's in your best interest to have a client be able spin up any number of executables on your web server.

Comment: I think the basic issue here is that most web browsers will not allow you to execute machine-level code (like C# programs) just from the user clicking something. Downloading and running is an option, or ClickOnce as an answer said, but you need to be made aware that this is not something the client's machine can run from just one click. This subscription app sounds like something that could be converted to HTML and JavaScript with a little bit of work.

Answer (score 1):

You can investigate `ClickOnce` deployment - if you want the application to launch client-side.

Launching apps `server-side` is a pretty big no-no, but possible using `Process.Start()` from your `aspx` (or `cshtml/vbhtml`) code-behind.

Comment: how would i use click once deployment, i published the application and am trying to run it again off a a href link but it doesn't work, i want it to appear as a pop up

Comment: That's an entirely different question.  Open a new SO question.  But before you do, you had better try to figure it out, or else you new question will get shut down before you get an answer (see the FAQ).